# git track, ignore, delete, untrack

Tags: git

I seem to have ballsed up my git repo by tracking a file, later ignoring it and then deleting it. The thing is, I want the file to be present in a remote repository (the live site), but just don't want to track.

Now my master branch is trying to remove all the files from the repository, which I know will delete them on the remote branch when I push changes... I just want to untrack them, but cannot do that as they're already deleted on master and git rm -r --cached says 'did not match any files'.

How can I untrack these deleted files without removing them from the remote repository?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just don't want to track a file, but you want to keep the file in the remote repository (non-bare).

Use this git command. After you do this, git stops checking the file for possible modifications.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  <filename>
```

At any time, you can track again by setting *--no-assume-unchaged* flag

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged  <filename>
```

These command do not affect the remote repository.

For more information: http://kar-git.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-set-git-to-ignore-few-files-like.html

Comment: Hei its working. Can you please explain how is it different from adding to git ignore

Comment: @ Ajith: GIT will not ignore a file that was already tracked. Look at the link provided in the answer for detailed information.

Answer (score 4):

`git rm` is used to delete files from the repository.

To stop tracking them, you can, after deleting, add them to the `.gitignore` file in the root of the repository.

Comment: I don't think you can stop tracking a file that is already tracked by gitignoring it. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Confirmed. !min char limit!

Comment: Yes. Removing with `rm` **will not** stop tracking them, removing with `git rm` **will** stop tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have untracked a file with git rm, you can still checkout a previous version of that file, e.g.

In your local repo:
git rm foo
git commit -m 'removed foo'
git push origin master

In the remote repository:

```
git pull origin master // foo will be removed
git checkout abcd1234 -- foo // checkout foo from commit abcd1234 (foo is staged)
git reset HEAD // unstage foo
git status

# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       foo
```

Then add to .gitignore to untrack