# Discard change from server

Tags: git

I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11209188/1834700) to not include local content to commit, by using this command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  <filename>
```

but when someone change it and push to server, i will receive this message when pull from server:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        <filename>
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

Is there anyway to not apply change from server to local files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue when trying to merge files which were ignored with `update-index --assume-unchanged`.

Sadly there is no clean solution, only workarounds.
You should revert the `--assume-unchanged` and then stash the changes so you can pull, after that you should pop your stash and resolve any possible merge conflicts.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <filename>
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
<Solve merge conflicts>
```

If you still want to ignore the file after that you can use `update index --assume-unchanged` again.

Hope that helps.

---

*Note*: If you have similar problems when switching branches after using `assume-unchanged` you should use `skip-worktree` (`git update-index --skip-worktree <filename>`).

You can find more information on this topic in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815416/preserve-git-assume-unchanged-files-between-branch-checkouts) and of course in the [documentation for `update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).

Comment: Thank you, may be i have to do some boring work, i will accept for some days. Thank you again!