# Define .gitignore file at user level and track changes only directory defined in gitignore in repository

Tags: git, gitignore, git-config

I've a situation where i want to define .gitignore file at user level. I would like to use both .gitignore repository as well as user level. Repository level is the same used by every one and user level is to add/remove files from tracking only for my machine.

We've a repository in which i work on a particular directory, so i want to push changes only for that directory. I don't want to accidently push changes for files outside that directory.

**I'm looking solution for**

- Add/Remove files from tracking in user level .gitignore file?
- In user level .gitignore, our path should be relative or absolute?
- Is it possible to add a directory in .gitignore I only want to keep track?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a user-specific gitignore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724455/can-i-make-a-user-specific-gitignore-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git track, ignore, delete, untrack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785792/git-track-ignore-delete-untrack)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, I was looking for

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

For more information:

[Already answered in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785792/git-track-ignore-delete-untrack/11209188#11209188)

[How to set GIT to ignore a few files](http://kar-git.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-set-git-to-ignore-few-files-like.html)