# Do not pull certain directory in git

Tags: git

I am working on a project which has several directories. One of them is massive (I'm talking tens of GB) and of no use to me. It is updated fairly regularly, so my pulls normally take a long time because of this, and it's quickly eating up my disk space.

I want my local copy of the git repository to not include that directory, and have my `git pull` commands ignore the directory, while keeping the repository the same for everyone else. The idea is to save time when pulling and save disk space.

Having the team using that directory move it to an independent repository has already been tried and it is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone, ignoring a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory)

Comment: why did putting the folder into a different repo not work? did you use subtree/submodules?

Comment: I think you answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785792/git-track-ignore-delete-untrack/11209188#11209188